# Making change to Heroku server

Tags: heroku

I inherited an app, and while I intend to redeploy everything correctly shortly with a host of other changes, a client of mine wants new branding up quickly on a Heroku server.

I access the server this way:

```
heroku run bash --app APPNAME
```

and I pulled down the file via wget and put it into a static files directory.

However, after doing this, the change is not reflected live. Is there anyway to make a temporary change like this without a full redeploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File systems on Heroku are ephemeral - the files get deleted and there is no persistence.

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to
>   the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
>   shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
>   filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many
>   container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

[Why Are My Files Deleted - Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)